# An algebra over a set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\{A_1,...,A_n\}$ a finite subset of $P(X)$ where $X$ is a non-empty set. Define $A^0=A$ and $A^1=X\setminus A$. For each $a\in\{0,1\}^n$, let $E_a=A^{a_1}\cap ...\cap A^{a_n}$.

I want to prove that if $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of all $\displaystyle\bigcup_{a\in D}E_a$ where $D\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra over $X$.

I already proved that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite unions and $X\in \mathcal{A}$.

Now I want to prove that if $\displaystyle\bigcup_{a\in D}E_a\in\mathcal{A}$ then $X\setminus\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{a\in D}E_a\right)\in\mathcal{A}$.

Of course, I know $X\setminus\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{a\in D}E_a\right)=\displaystyle\bigcap_{a\in D}(X\setminus E_a)$.

But I don't know how to prove it is in $\mathcal{A}$.

Any hint? Thanks :)